# How to delete/detect what command-line software I have installed?

Tags: macos, terminal, macports, pip

On Mac OS X Terminal, I installed many terminal programs while trying to install a programming library. Now I'm wondering how I delete them. I think some of them include pip, macports, vmenven (or something). I'm not sure what these programs are called but they all are called from the command line using something like "macports..." (so I'm calling them terminal programs). First, how do I tell what terminal programs are installed. Second, how do I delete them. And, to be through, where are the programs stored anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDITED

Here's a [List of terminal Emulators for MAC OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators#Mac_OS_X)

To uninstall applications:

> By default Mac OS X software is stored in the Applications folder on your hard drive.
>
> Drag the program’s icon or folder to the Trash to begin the uninstall process.

Detailed Information can be found at [How To Completely Uninstall Software under Mac OS X [MacRx]](http://www.cultofmac.com/90060/how-to-completely-uninstall-software-under-mac-os-x-macrx/)

---

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

The name [macports](http://www.macports.org/), that you are referring to, is an easy-to-use system that allows you to install applications:

> The MacPorts Project is an open-source community initiative to design an easy-to-use system for compiling, installing, and upgrading either command-line, X11 or Aqua based open-source software on the Mac OS X operating system.
>
> It allows the installation of a number of packages by entering the command sudo port install packagename in the Terminal, which will then download, if necessary compile and install the requested software, while also installing any required dependencies automatically. Installed packages can be updated with the command sudo port selfupdate.

Uninstalling a program previously installed with macports requires some considerations. A full explanation to your problem can be found at this http://apple.stackexchange.com question:

[How to remove unused MacPorts packages?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/10149/24524)

There you will find the necessary steps and links to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I,m really wondering for a way to list all cmd line apps on my system. My question was probable  unclear since I mentioned Mac ports, but that's just one of the many software I installed.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my question was edited and no longer reflects what I wanted to know. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MikeG, just updated the answer with new information. Hope it Helps!